# Is there some sort of classification of invertible finite groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let’s call a group $G$ invertible, if $\forall H \triangleleft G$, there $\exists K \triangleleft G$, such, that $K \cong \frac{G}{H}$ and $H \cong \frac{G}{K}$

All finite abelian groups are known to be invertible. All simple groups also are invertible.

However the vast majority of finite groups seems to be non-invertible: that includes symmetric groups, dihedral groups, holomorphs of cyclic groups, generalised quaternion groups and so on…

So my question is:

> Is there some sort of classification of invertible finite groups?

Comment: Are the isomorphisms $K\to G/H$ and $H\to G/K$ allowed to be arbitrary or should they be induced by the inclusions?

Comment: @Christoph, yes, they are allowed to be arbitrary.

Comment: A direct product of a finite abelian group with a collection of nonabelian simple groups is also invertible.

Comment: It almost seems your definition itself is a classification of sorts ... are there other ways of defining what an invertible group is besides the one you have given?

Comment: How is the definition of an invertible group close to a classification in itself? For example, can you name a few invertible $p$-groups of small order?